# What is the difference between mock and mock_model in RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

I've recently came across different tutorials, where people use both **`mock`** and **`mock_model`** functions.

In [RSpec tutorial for controllers](http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-rails#Controller_Specs) they use the **`mock_model`** function, but right in the [documentation of RSpec](http://rspec.rubyforge.org/rspec/1.2.8/), there is only **`mock`** function, but no **`mock_model`**

I tried to run some tests myself, and I didn't find any real difference, since everything was ok when I used either of those two functions, so is there any difference at all?

Comment: For people finding this question ranking in Google for "rspec mock_model", the best documentation can be found at https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/mocks/mock-model

Answer (score 33, accepted):

As jenger said mock_model is an extension built for active record:

This is the source in 1.2.6:

```
     def mock_model(model_class, options_and_stubs = {})
        id = options_and_stubs[:id] || next_id
        options_and_stubs = options_and_stubs.reverse_merge({
          :id => id,
          :to_param => id.to_s,
          :new_record? => false,
          :errors => stub("errors", :count => 0)
        })
        m = mock("#{model_class.name}_#{id}", options_and_stubs)
        m.__send__(:__mock_proxy).instance_eval <<-CODE
          def @target.as_new_record
            self.stub!(:id).and_return nil
            self.stub!(:to_param).and_return nil
            self.stub!(:new_record?).and_return true
            self
          end
          def @target.is_a?(other)
            #{model_class}.ancestors.include?(other)
          end
          def @target.kind_of?(other)
            #{model_class}.ancestors.include?(other)
          end
          def @target.instance_of?(other)
            other == #{model_class}
          end
          def @target.class
            #{model_class}
          end
        CODE
        yield m if block_given?
        m
      end
```

So its quite a mouthful, but it

- stubs the id with the next in a sequence
- stubs to_param
- stubs new_record? with false
- stubs errors so it thinks there are no errors

It also extends the model instance with a bunch of stuff.

Answer (score 9):

From: [Useful helpers for RSpec mocks](http://kpumuk.info/rspec/useful-helpers-for-rspec-mocks/)

> Firstly, `mock_model` automatically
>   defines unique ids for models, which
>   were created using it. Secondly, it
>   defines methods `to_param` (returns
>   string representation of the id) and
>   `new_record?` (returns false).